# Arc sweep direction in two.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry, drawing, two.js

two.js library has a function as follows;

```
makeArcSegment two.makeArcSegment(ox, oy, ir, or, sa, ea, res);
```

I calculate my parameters as follows;

```
var prevPt = points[i - 1];

var dxNext = nextPt.x - pt.x;
var dyNext = nextPt.y - pt.y;
var angleNext = Math.atan2(dyNext, dxNext);

var dxPrev = prevPt.x - pt.x;
var dyPrev = prevPt.y - pt.y;
var anglePrev = Math.atan2(dyPrev, dxPrev);

var innerRadius = 0;
var outerRadius = 20;

var arc = two.makeArcSegment(pt.x, pt.y, innerRadius, outerRadius, anglePrev, angleNext)
```

And my output is kind of unexpected.

[image]

At first node (after the line with the length of 225.46), sweep direction is counter clockwise.
At second node (after 142.35), sweep direction is clockwise.How do I force it to be always counter clockwise?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/jonobr1/two.js/issues/206)  `if you make the arc.endAngle less than the arc.startAngle then it should go in the opposite direction.`.

So you can try to draw between `min(prev,next)` and `max(prev,next)` as workaround.

Also make all angles positive (adding 2*Pi to negative ones).

Looks like serious flaw of library though.

Comment: Yes, your first statement is right, and it's been a workaround for me, however I already tried min,max method but It didn't affect the output.

Comment: Does exchange of all `anglePrev, angleNext` influence on output?

Comment: Have you tried to "cast" all angles into 0.2*Pi range (adding 2Pi to negative ones)?

Comment: exchange of angleprev and angleNext doesn't  affect output either. I posted the workaround I found. 
1. Make everything positive, 
2. Make prevousAngle greater than nextAngle.

Comment: OK, so I move assumption about range into answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the workaround I found.

```
      if (anglePrev < 0.0)
      {
          anglePrev += Math.PI * 2.0;
      }
      if (angleNext < 0.0)
      {
          angleNext += Math.PI * 2.0;
      }
      if (angleNext > anglePrev)
      {
          anglePrev += Math.PI * 2.0;
      }
```